# Handle class and assignment operator

Tags: c++, oop

I have a simple handle class that I use to control objects of inherited classes. Here is the simple implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

class ParametersInner
{

  public:
    ParametersInner() {}
    virtual ~ParametersInner() {}

    virtual ParametersInner *clone() const = 0;
};

class ParametersConstant : public ParametersInner
{
  public:
    ParametersConstant(){};

    virtual ParametersInner *clone() const { return new ParametersConstant(*this); }
};

class Parameters
{
  public:
    Parameters(const ParametersInner &innerObject)
    {
        std::cout << "CC (and implicit conversion)\n";
        InnerObjectPtr = innerObject.clone();
    }
    Parameters(const Parameters &original)
    {
        std::cout << "CC\n";
        InnerObjectPtr = original.InnerObjectPtr->clone();
    }
    Parameters &operator=(const Parameters &original)
    {
        std::cout << "AO\n";
        if (this != &original)
        {
            delete InnerObjectPtr;
            InnerObjectPtr = original.InnerObjectPtr->clone();
        }
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~Parameters() { delete InnerObjectPtr; }

  private:
    ParametersInner *InnerObjectPtr;
};

int main()
{
    ParametersConstant VolParam;

    ///this is identical to (Parameters)VolParam so it calls the copy constructor. But why does it not call the assignment operator = afterwards?
    Parameters Vol = VolParam;

    ///calls copy constructor - OK
    Parameters Vol_0(Vol);

    ///calls assignment operator - OK
    Vol_0 = Vol;

    return 0;
}
```

The code is rather simple, but there is one aspect that I can't figure out, which is related to the line `Parameters Vol = VolParam;`. As I understand it, basically what this line translates into is `Parameters Vol = (Parameters)VolParam;`, i.e., there is a type conversion.

However, after the conversion why isn't the assignment operator called? How else is `Vol` created?

Comment: No, it's not type conversion but implicit construction.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I did so now, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
Parameters Vol = VolParam;
```

because that's the way we did in C (`int i = 0;`), but unless you put extra effort in the class declaration (with `explicit` constructors) the effect is the same as

```
Parameters Vol(VolParam);
```

And despite the use of the `=` token, this is not an assignment.

`Vol = VolParam;`, without a type name, is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

> the line Parameters `Vol = VolParam;`. As I understand it, basically what this line translates into is Parameters `Vol = (Parameters)VolParam;`, i.e., there is a type conversion.
>
> However, after the conversion why isn't the assignment operator called? How else is Vol created?

It's not assignment nor type conversion, but implicit construction.
This is the constructor declaration that allows that:

```
Parameters(const ParametersInner &innerObject)
{
    std::cout << "CC (and implicit conversion)\n";
    InnerObjectPtr = innerObject.clone();
}
```

To prevent this use the `explicit` keyword with the constructor declaration.